# Javascript filter array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does the following function return undefined when executed?
Seems as though the filter function does indeed return the appropriate object so I'm not seeing why it can't be passed to the callback function. I'm very new to JS.

```
function getUserById(usersArr, userId, cb){
  cb((usersArr.filter(function(el){
    return el.id === userId;
  })[0]));
} 
getUserById(users, '15a', function(user){
  return 'The user with the id 15a has the email of ' + user.email + ' the name of ' + user.name + ' and the address of ' + user.address;
}); 

var users = [
  {
    id: '43d',
    email: 'james@gmail.com',
    name: 'james',
    address: '16 N'
  },
  {
    id: '15a',
    email: 'carry@gmail.com',
    name: 'Carry',
    address: '14 N'
  },
  {
    id: '87t',
    email: 'jeff@gmail.com',
    name: 'Jeff',
    address: '23 N'
  },
];
```

Comment: Don't make us assume. Actually post an example array.

Comment: Ok example array posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of objects, and one or more of those objects have the ID property assigned to '15a', your filter should work.

Here's an example:

```
function getUserById(usersArr, userId, cb) {
    cb(usersArr.filter(function (el) {
        return el.id === userId;
    })[0]);
}

var users = [{
    id: '15a',
    name: 'bob',
    email: 'bob@example.com',
    address: '123 main street'
}, {
    id: 'zxv',
    name: 'jim',
    email: 'jim@example.com',
    address: '234 main ave'
}];

getUserById(users, '15a', function (user) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'The user with the id 15a has the email of ' + user.email + ' the name of ' + user.name + ' and the address of ' + user.address;
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0skhn9k9/2/

Edit: to make your example work you need to return the value of the callback

```
function getUserById(usersArr, userId, cb){
  return cb((usersArr.filter(function(el){
    return el.id === userId;
  })[0]));
} 
getUserById(users, '15a', function(user){
  return 'The user with the id 15a has the email of ' + user.email + ' the name of ' + user.name + ' and the address of ' + user.address;
}); 

var users = [
  {
    id: '43d',
    email: 'james@gmail.com',
    name: 'james',
    address: '16 N'
  },
  {
    id: '15a',
    email: 'carry@gmail.com',
    name: 'Carry',
    address: '14 N'
  },
  {
    id: '87t',
    email: 'jeff@gmail.com',
    name: 'Jeff',
    address: '23 N'
  },
];
```

Comment: Be aware, if you are trying to return the value of a callback that hasn't executed yet. It will be undefined. I would suggest writing an output method that the callback calls to assign or output data.

Comment: Thanks. I was running it in repl.it and see now what the issues were, too. JSFiddle is great

Comment: This answer does not answer the question *Why does the following function return undefined when executed?*

Comment: Thanks, I elaborated a bit on my answer.